# Windows Internal Database missing on Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, wsus

I had to reinstall WSUS, so I removed WSUS and reinstalled it, then WID service could not start, so I removed WSUS again and deleted "WID" service.

Now when I re-install WSUS it says WID is installed, but WID service is missing from services.msc

I even tried installing it through powershell command `Install-WindowsFeature Windows-Internal-Database`  and it shows success but if I refresh services.msc it is still missing.

Any suggestions?

I followed the following procedure to uninstall:

1. Remove WSUS role followed by IIS role
2. Remove Windows Internal Database from Roles/Features
3. Rename WID folder from "C:\Windows\WID" which contains "SUSDB.mdf"
4. reboot
5. install WSUS with IIS with all supportive features including WID.

Comment: I suspect that though the WID service is missing in the services.msc list, everything is in place; try this command on elevated CMD to create entry of WID in services.msc (please test first on UAT WSUS): `sc create "Windows Internal Database" binpath= "C:\Windows\WID\Binn\sqlservr.exe -SMSWIN8.SQLWID -sMICROSOFT#" type= own start= auto depend= "WIDWriter"`. Also, refer this article for more info: https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/251192/how-to-create-a-windows-service-by-using-sc-exe

Comment: your solution sounds like it might work, but in `C:\Windows\WID\' there is only `DBVerify` folder and inside that `SUSDBVerify.dll` file. And i can't find sqlserver.exe anywhere in `C:\Program files`

Comment: looks like WID isn't being installed correctly and hence no sqlserver.exe?  I have another WSUS on win2008r2 and it has SQLservr.exe located in `C:\Windows\SYSMSI\SSEE\MSSQL.2005\MSSQL\Binn\` but on 2012 server there is no `C:\Windows\SYSMSI\`

Comment: I am also inclined to think that WID has not been installed correctly! If nothing helps, and if it is possible for you, please build the server from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following are the steps to resolve the bug.

- uninstall WSUS and WID
- Rename WID folder from "C:\Windows\WID" which contains "SUSDB.mdf"
- reboot
- install only WID feature and change its service logon account
- start WID service
- install WSUS